# How can I return a Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,decimal>> from this method?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a LINQ statement which returns an IQueryable of the class below.

Class:

```
public class SupplierSummaryReport {
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string SupplierName { get; set; }
            public decimal TurnOverValues { get; set; }
        }
```

Eg: `{2012,Supplier1,90},{2011,Supplier2,95}`

However, I then need to convert this data into a Dictionary of Dictionaries. I have the extension method which me and a friend have built, however we are stumped at the final section.

Extension Method:

```
public static Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>> Pivot<TSource, TFirstKey, TSecondKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TFirstKey> firstKeySelector, Func<TSource, TSecondKey> secondKeySelector, Func<TSource, TValue> Value) {
            var retVal = new Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>>();

            var l = source.ToLookup(firstKeySelector);
            foreach (var item in l) {
                var dict = new Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>();
                retVal.Add(item.Key, dict);
                var subdict = item.ToLookup(secondKeySelector);
                foreach (var subitem in subdict) {
                    dict.Add(subitem.Key, subitem.Value /*Insert value here*/);
                }
            }

            return retVal;
        }
```

We call the method like so:

```
public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,decimal>> GetSupplierSummaryReportData(List<int> last5Years) {
            _ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60;
            //values - Gets the data required for the Supplier summary report in a hierachical order. E.g - {2012,Supplier1,3},{2011,Supplier1,4}
            var values = (from i in _ctx.Invoices
                          where i.Turnover == true
                          group i by new { i.AccountName, i.InvoiceDate.Year } into summ
                          select new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport {
                              Year = summ.Key.Year,
                              SupplierName = summ.Key.AccountName,
                              TurnOverValues = summ.Sum(r => r.VATAmount_Home ?? 0)
                          });

            //accounts - Get all the account names
            var accounts = (from i in _ctx.Invoices
                            where i.Turnover == true
                            group i by new { i.AccountName } into summ
                            select new {
                                summ.Key.AccountName
                            });

            /*crossJoin - select all SupplierNames from accounts and all years from last5Years and assign each SupplierName the last 5 years. Assign each turnover value null for each year.
            This is in preparation for the cross join as not all suppliers will have the last 5 year in data */

            var crossJoin = accounts.SelectMany(a => last5Years, (a, y) => new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport {
                Year = y,
                SupplierName = a.AccountName,
                TurnOverValues = 0
            });

            /*Join crossJoin and values together, wherever the join is empty, assign the cross join values. If not assign the turnover value from a*/

            var result =
                (from cj in crossJoin
                 join v in values
                 on new { cj.Year, cj.SupplierName }
                 equals new { v.Year, v.SupplierName } into lJoin
                 from a in lJoin.DefaultIfEmpty(new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport {
                     Year = cj.Year,
                     SupplierName = cj.SupplierName,
                     TurnOverValues = cj.TurnOverValues
                 })
                 select new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport {
                     Year = cj.Year,
                     SupplierName = cj.SupplierName,
                     TurnOverValues = a.TurnOverValues
                 }).OrderBy(r => r.SupplierName).ThenBy(r => r.Year);

            return result.Pivot(r => r.SupplierName, c => c.Year, y => y.TurnOverValues);
```

We need to insert the decimal value of `TurnOverValues` as the third item in the dictionary.

Expected outcome:

```
{Supplier1, {2012,60}}, {Supplier2, {2014,90}}
```

If anyone needs anymore information, please let me know.

Comment: Just saying, that is one large signature for an extension method. Are you sure you need a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: @Hayden Yeah, the data is in a hierarchical order in the database and the view needs the data in a flatter model and unfortunately, this is the only way we can think of

Comment: When you approach to point like yours - when you have triple or more nested generic classes, you shoud probably stop and think of creating own hierarchy of classes (which could obviously inherit from those Dictionary<*,*>), because after a month you will be unable to understand the hierarchy that you have created. Not to mention readability of your code for other programmers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR, but if what you have is an `IEnumerable<SupplierSummaryReport>` and you're sure that each `SupplierName, Year, TurnOver` combination is unique or can be made unique then `ToDictionary` makes this easy:

```
var data = new List<SupplierSummaryReport> { ... };

// avoiding var just to verify correct result Type
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, decimal>> result = data
    .GroupBy(ssr => ssr.SupplierName)
    .ToDictionary(g1 => g1.Key, g1 => (
            g1.GroupBy(g2 => g2.Year)
              .ToDictionary(g3 => g3.Key, 
                            g3 => g3.First().TurnOverValues))
      );
```

Maybe the `g3.First()` should become `.Single()` or `.Sum()` or something.